# How to get friendly_id gem get working with Rails 5.0.0.rc1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using friendly_id in my rails app. I have the following in the gemfile.

```
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'
```

I get 404 error whenever I visit a user profile.

```
suai@rails-tutorial:~/workspace/iya (master) $ rails server -b $IP -p $PORT
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 5.0.0.rc1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[2016-06-07 05:54:21] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-06-07 05:54:21] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-06-07 05:54:21] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=74846 port=8080
Started GET "/users/testtest" for 98.5.56.144 at 2016-06-07 05:54:25 +0000
Cannot render console from 98.5.56.144! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"testtest"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering public/404.html within layouts/application
  Rendered public/404.html within layouts/application (8.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.2ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 924ms (Views: 848.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

User controller, show method

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js    
    end      
  end
```

User.rb

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

I figured that friendly_id is not working.
Any idea how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Can you post what params are passed to your method. And the error you get in your rails server console?

Comment: Okay, can you post the contents of your users#show method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you have to do is user `Model.friendly.find` instead of `find`.

```
def show
  @user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js    
  end      
end
```

I hope you have extended your model with `FriendlyId`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey it works. Thank you. But I have this "friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]". Should it be "friendly_id :foo, use: :slugged" ?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. No its just an example. Yours is fine.

Comment: Thanks. But if I have "friendly_id :foo, use: [:slugged, :finders]", this "User.find(params[:id])" should work right? I should be using "User.friendly.find(params[:id])" only if I have this "friendly_id :foo, use: :slugged" right? As per https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: Correct. use `friendly_id :name, use: :slugged`. You should be able to find by `User.friendly.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Thank you. So, "friendly_id :foo, use: [:slugged, :finders]" doesn't work with Rails 5.0.0.rc1?

Comment: I haven't tried it in rails 5. I think you should raise an error at their github, if you confirm. :)

Comment: Thanks this works. Should this be done only in the controllers? Do I have to do the same in the view? I do <%= link_to User.find_by(id: 12654).name, user_path(User.find_by(id: 12654)), target: "_blank" %>

Answer (score 4):

When you want to use...

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

... you need to install the master branch (friendly_id 5.2.0.beta.1)

```
gem 'friendly_id', github: 'norman/friendly_id'
```

If you do so, you don't have to change the controllers (Model.friendly.find)

Answer (score 3):

update to 5.2.1 solve it.

```
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.1'
```

Comment: it does not help

Comment: @bmalets did you get it fixed? How so? 
I'm running into this behavior and I'm on `5.2.5`

Comment: I used a suggestion from the first answer (model with `friendly` scope)